# Overloading Java function (insert into binary tree)

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, overloading

I have a binary tree below and it seems to make sense to overload the `insert()` method. If `insert()` is called without a `Node` specified, it will just work with `head`, otherwise if it receives a `Node`, it will do the insert in the subtree starting with that `Node`. This second variant is then called recursively, see below.

The repetition that happens in the code below seems wrong to me (not DRY). Is there a better way to do this or is this a limitation in Java?

```
public class probBinaryTree {
    public Node head;

    public probBinaryTree() {
        this.head = null;
    }   

    private class Node {
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int size;

        public Node(int d) {
            this.data = d;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
            this.size = 1;
        }
    }

    public Node insert(int d) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(d);
            return head;
        }
        head.size++;
        if (head.left == null) return insert(head.left, d);
        if (head.right == null) return insert(head.right, d);
        if (head.left.size <= head.right.size) return insert(head.left, d);
        if (head.left.size > head.right.size) return insert(head.right, d);
        return null;
    }

    private Node insert(Node n, int d) {
        if (n == null) {
            n = new Node(d);
            return n;
        }
        n.size++;
        if (n.left == null) return insert(n.left, d);
        if (n.right == null) return insert(n.right, d);
        if (n.left.size <= n.right.size) return insert(n.left, d);
        if (n.left.size > n.right.size) return insert(n.right, d);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have one `insert` method call the other. In your code, that would look like:

```
public final class BinaryTree {

    public Node head;

    public BinaryTree() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    private class Node {
        private final int data;
        private final Node left;
        private final Node right;
        private int size;

        public Node(final int d) {
            this.data = d;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
            this.size = 1;
        }
    }

    public Node insert(final int d) {
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = new Node(d);
            return this.head;
        }

        return this.insert(this.head, d);
    }

    private Node insert(final Node n, final int d) {
        if (n == null) {
            return new Node(d);
        }

        n.size++;
        if (n.left == null) {
            return this.insert(n.left, d);
        }
        if (n.right == null) {
            return this.insert(n.right, d);
        }
        if (n.left.size <= n.right.size) {
            return this.insert(n.left, d);
        }
        if (n.left.size > n.right.size) {
            return this.insert(n.right, d);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```